# R: TinyTex Installation Error: `Error in xfun::download_file(..., quiet = Sys.getenv("APPVEYOR") != "") `

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr, tinytex

I've attempted installing `tinytex` in my system using the usual `tinytex::install_tinytex()`. However, it resulted to the following error:

```r
> tinytex::install_tinytex()
trying URL 'https://yihui.org/tinytex/TinyTeX-1.zip'
trying URL 'https://yihui.org/tinytex/TinyTeX-1.zip'
trying URL 'https://yihui.org/tinytex/TinyTeX-1.zip'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   134    0   134    0     0      7      0 --:--:--  0:00:17 --:--:--    37
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ci.appveyor.com
Error in xfun::download_file(..., quiet = Sys.getenv("APPVEYOR") != "") : 
  No download method works (auto/wininet/wget/curl/lynx)
```

I can't seem to find the source of this problem. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why your `curl` couldn't connect to `ci.appveyor.com`, but there are alternative ways to install TinyTeX, e.g.,

```r
tinytex::install_tinytex(version = "latest")
```